# Writing multiple passes in oracle sql or pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am used to writing code in CCL where I had been creating reports which extract data and store them in record structures, and I usually write in multiple passes. Is it possible to do that with oracle SQL?

For example I am using one pass to extract data from 4 tables and store in a record structure. Then in the new pass  I extract use the previous record structure and add more tables to extract more data in the end use the final record structure to print what I want.

I am not sure how to replicate that in SQL.

Comment: If you're inserting and updating records in a collection (a list of record structures), then you should consider the option of not entirely replicating the CCL code. If I were to envision the code, it executes a select statement, fetches its rows into a collection and then iterates over each member of the collection. In each iteration, it updates members of the current element depending upon the results of one or more statements. Generally speaking, I wouldn't advocate that approach unless there was no way to optimize a conglomerate query that would allow you to join in SQL instead of PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. PL/SQL has **records**, which are basically structures, and three types of **collections**. And you can create a collection of records, then loop over it.

Collections can be:

1. Nested tables, like `TYPE varchar_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30)`
2. Associative arrays or "index-by arrays", like `TYPE varchar_aa IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`
3. VARRAYs, which have a fixed maximum size and I pretty much never use them

There are subtle differences between the three types. Nested tables can be defined at the schema level and stored in tables. Associative arrays must be defined in PL/SQL.

Nested tables can be used in SQL like a table with the `TABLE()` function. Associative arrays could not be used in SQL until recent versions and still have some limitations.

You can loop over collections `FOR` or use `FORALL` if you're going to do a single SQL statement with the collection.

See [PL/SQL Collections and Records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A) in the documentation.